# mysql find outstanding entries

Tags: php, mysql

```
Transaction Code   Credit Debit  Date         Year  Month   Transaction Type    Paid By    Customer ID   Reference 
1110101            100    0      2013-06-26   2013  7           RVC              Cash        10547         4010101
4010101            0      100    2013-07-01   2013  7           INV                                          10547         0
```

Above is a Transaction table. Any transaction happens is dumped here.

Now the challenging part here is I need to get all the Outstanding Payments due for the Year for all the customers in 2013. RVC (under transaction type) refers to the amount being paid, where as INV (under transaction type) refers to amount not paid yet. The two rows which you are seeing is The INV which was raised and subsequently paid which shows in RVC. Now each month automatically the INV is created and whenever some payment is there RVC is created.

Now how do I know which INV is left to be paid. as its very confusing to compare since the Reference plus the Year plus the Month needs to be compared with the RVC if its paid.

How can we achieve it via MySQL query???

Any help on this?

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results.  It is a bit hard to understand the business rules you are trying to apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for open payments you can use something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions
     WHERE transaction_type='INV' 
     AND transaction_code 
        NOT IN (SELECT reference FROM transactions where transaction_type='RVC');
```

**EDIT:**

Since this is a fairly expensive query on a large table, I'd probably store the customer id in the customer ID field in the INV lines, and leave the reference field as null.
When processing a payment, update the reference field in the corresponding INV line to the payment reference the id of the 'RVC' line. This should be easy since you are finding the correct Transaction Code to insert into the 'RVC' line. You can then update the 'INV' record with the reference you are creating (the current RVC line)

```
UPDATE transactions SET reference=$rvc_id WHERE transaction_code=$inv_id;
```

So after a payment has been processed, the reference field will be filled in.
Unpaid INV lines will have a blank reference, that will mean to check for unpaid 'INV' you'll just have to run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transaction_type='INV' AND reference IS NULL;
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but if I do that reference is NULL, it will also show the records which are paid, since the INV records is only linked with RVC record by comparing Transaction Code with Reference and Year and Month. So how I can crack this? You see the INV record never gets updated if a payment is made. If a payment is made an RVC record is created.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading it wrong. I thought the first record was the INV and the second the RVC. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes thanks, the query is indeed very expensive and its' taking years to process it. Not an ideal solution for web based or for any other. Could there be an any other optimized query for this as the issue with this is that table which I'm updating is being used by a Back Office, so cannot alter it.

Comment: One thing you can do to help speed things up may be to include the year and/or month in the main query and the sub-query `WHERE year=2013 AND month=3 AND transaction_type=...`